# Project Reactor and Server Side Events

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, project-reactor, reactive

I'm looking for a solution that will have the backend publish an event to the frontend as soon as a modification is done on the server side. To be more concise I want to emit a new List of objects as soon as one item is modified.

I've tried implementing on a SpringBoot project, that uses Reactive Web, MongoDB which has a @Tailable cursor that publish an event as soon as the capped collection is modified. The problem is that the capped collection has some limitation and is not really compatible with what I want to do. The thing is I cannot update an existing element if the new one has a different size(as I understood this is illegal because you cannot make a rollback).

I honestly don't even know if it's doable, but maybe I'm lucky and I'll run into a rocket scientist right here that will prove otherwise.

Thanks in advance!!

*** EDIT:
Sorry for the vague question. Yes I'm more focused on the HOW, using the Spring Reactive framework.

Comment: Please try to organize and rephrase the question. What is it specifically that you're looking for? The problem is in detecting the moment WHEN an event needs to be published? Or is the problem about HOW to publish something from backend to frontend?

Answer (score 0):

When I had a similar need - to inform frontend that something is done on the backend side - I have used a message queue.

I have published a message to the queue from the backend and the frontend consumed the message.

But I am not sure if that is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using webflux with spring reactor, I think you can simply have a client request with content-type as 'text/event-stream' or 'application/stream+json' and You shall have API that can produce those content-type. This gives you SSE model without too much effort.

```
@GetMapping(value = "/stream", produces = {MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_STREAM_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE})
public Flux<Message> get(HttpServletRequest request) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Just as an idea - maybe you need to use a web socket technology here:

The frontend side (I assume its a client side application that runs in a browser, written in react, angular or something like that) can establish a web-socket communication with the backend server.

When the process on backend finishes, the message from backend to frontend can be sent.

Answer (score 0):

You can do emitting changes by hand. For example:

endpoint:

```
public final Sinks.Many<SimpleInfoEvent> infoEventSink = Sinks.many().multicast().onBackpressureBuffer();

@RequestMapping(path = "/sseApproach", produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
public Flux<ServerSentEvent<SimpleInfoEvent>> sse() {
    return infoEventSink.asFlux()
            .map(e -> ServerSentEvent.builder(e)
                    .id(counter.incrementAndGet() + "")
                    .event(e.getClass().getName())
                    .build());
}
```

Code anywhere for emitting data:

```
infoEventSink.tryEmitNext(new SimpleInfoEvent("any custom event"));
```

Watch out of threads and things like "subscribeOn", "publishOn", but basically (when not using any third party code), this should work good enough.